# Caret in custom tooltip for chartjs

Tags: graph, charts, chart.js, tooltip, caret

I am trying to create a custom tooltip using ChartJs. So far I have managed to control the CSS of the title, and labels within the tooltip, but I am not able to get the "caret" on the tooltip.

Current:
[Custom Tooltip without caret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EC6D.png)

Expected:
[Custom Tooltip with caret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CKVd.png)

I tried the tutorial of ChartJs documentation as well have looked into multiple codepens.

Refer this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/chart-js-html-tooltip
This follows the tutorial but the caret is still missing on this.

I tried tinkering around with these two in chartjs configurations:

```
// Set caret Position

  tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
  if (tooltip.yAlign) {
    tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltip.yAlign);
  } else {
    tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
  }
```

and

```
 const positionY = this._chart.canvas.offsetTop;
  const positionX = this._chart.canvas.offsetLeft;

  // Display, position, and set styles for font for tooltip element
  tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1 as any;
  tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + tooltip.caretX + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.top = positionY + tooltip.caretY + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltip.xPadding + 'px';
```

You can edit this https://stackblitz.com/edit/chart-js-html-tooltip to answer